# Removable volume not appearing in file managers

Tags: file-manager, udisks, gvfs

Neither Nautilus, Caja or Thunar show my removable storage device in the list of devices.

I can mount it manually using udisksctl:

```
$ udisksctl mount --block-device /dev/sdd1 Mounted /dev/sdd1 at
/run/media/user/RECOVERY.
```

It shows up in gvfs:

```
$ gio mount -l
...
"Drive(4): Generic Flash Disk
```

But gvfs can't mount it:

```
$ gio mount -d /dev/sdd1 
gio: /dev/sdd1: No volume for device file"
```

Nothing I've tried seems to work.

Answer (score 3):

It turns out that udisks has an attribute for drives that [marks them as ignored](http://storaged.org/doc/udisks2-api/latest/gdbus-org.freedesktop.UDisks2.Block.html#gdbus-property-org-freedesktop-UDisks2-Block.HintIgnore).

You can see if this attribute is set with the following:

```
$ udevadm info /dev/sdd1  | grep -i ignore
UDISKS_IGNORE=1
```

Udisks sets this attribute on devices based on heuristics and configuration. See [man udisks](http://storaged.org/doc/udisks2-api/latest/udisks.8.html) and search for ignore.

In this case it turns out that partitions named "RECOVERY" among others are set as ignored by the default udev rules. See [here](https://github.com/storaged-project/udisks/blob/adc3d3f1c32f200eae71dd0b7532c83f5acc1a70/data/80-udisks2.rules#L143).

**So the solution was to rename my linux recovery usb stick to something else than "RECOVERY".**

Comment: Now that was a quick solution.

Comment: Thank you! This was very helpful, I was going down a rabbit hole of trying to figure out between Thunar and gvfs why a particular USB thumb drive was suddenly not showing up as user-mountable. I'm guessing they do this for e.g. dual boot machines, but it sure was confusing when I was intentionally wanting access to a completely separate machine's USB recovery image!